# FileManager for NetBeans

Tags: android, netbeans, file-management

I am developing fot Android using NetBeans. I have moved from Eclipse, where I have often used file explorer, for pushing and pulling data from and to device.

Is there in Netbeans simple window, if co, how to activate?

Thanks

Comment: Good question. You may add an include path of the device to your project; I don't know if that helps. The file-window (Window->Files) is just displaying files within the project folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To anyone still wondering, the Android SDK comes with a tool called DDMS located at

```
<android sdk>\tools\ddms.bat
```

that also has a file explorer once the program is open, located at

```
Device>File Explorer...
```

[You can read more about DDMS from the android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html)

Comment: Good idea, I've added it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to access a directory that is locally "available" (e.g. a drive in Windows, or something mounted in *Nix), then you can simply use the "Favorites" window and add that directory (or multiple directories) to that.

Then you can access the files directly in an "Explorer" like fashion.

The Favorites Window is available through "Window -> Favorites"

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I don't see any way how to access android file explorer (= files in my emulator)